# How to add Delete button to a calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

Working on advanced calculator with JavaScript but the delete function is not working

```
input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1)
```

it was supposed to delete one value, but it just turned the entired input to a string and totally made my input invalid

Comment: That's not even valid syntax. Please post your actual code.

Comment: `input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do this, the first that comes to mind is doing this:

```js
input.value = Number(input.value.toString().slice(0, -1));
```